# How do you actually utilize coding to produce projects?

Tags: programming-languages

I’m new to the whole programming society and the languages I’m learning right now are C++ and Lua. But as I’m learning it I can’t help but wonder how simple syntax such as print and if statements and such are used to program websites, games and more. I understand that they are the backbone of the entire project; it’s what makes them functional but how do you connect them to other resources such as graphics, visuals, and more. Are there any programs designed to do that? How do you actually make projects?

Comment: One step at a time

Comment: How do builders use pieces of wood and screws to build a house?

Comment: It's called software architecture.While a dollhouse might not need it, a house for humans (or an application that is sold as a product) will definitely need some architecture. (Remark. Selling a poorly-designed software product is a violation of commerce code in most countries.)

Comment: How do you eat an elephant?

Comment: "How do I do graphics, visuals, and more?" -> "How do I do graphics?" -> "[How do I draw an image on my screen in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576182/the-easiest-way-to-draw-an-image)", and now you have a good Google query to get you rolling.

Answer (score 5):

Usually this is done by utilizing work done by others. For example, you mention games. Games often use a framework or game engine (such as Unity, Unreal Engine, etc.). Those engines in turn use either OS-provided, or GPU-vendor provided libraries for producing graphics. Things like OpenGL, DirectX, Metal, etc. Those frameworks in turn implement data structures and algorithms developed over decades by academics, companies, and even governments.

It's the same with websites. They are stored on servers which use networking protocols in the OS to deliver packets from them to you. Your browser reads the data from the networking code on your computer, parses it using techniques and libraries developed by others (and also with some original components), and uses text and graphics libraries to layout and draw the page.

Everything done with computers is building on previous work. Even if you work in assembly language, you're writing code for the instruction set that the CPU vendor created, and assembling it to machine code using an assembler the OS vendor or an open source project created.

I should add that you will of course need to add a lot of your own code, as well to most projects that do any significant work. You'll find there are known ways of organizing and manipulating data that work better in some situations than others. As you do more, you'll gain a more intuitive idea of what to use when. And when you get it wrong, you'll learn about tools that help you figure out why it's wrong and maybe even how to fix it.